# Should we report R-squared or adjusted R-squared in non-linear regression?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, r-squared, reporting

I am running a non-linear regression for a dose response with the equation:

$$Y  = \frac{c}{1 + \big(\frac x g\big)^b}$$

When reporting my results for publication, do I report the R-squared or Adjusted R-squared, and why?

Comment: You seem to have only one x-variable. Do the two differ?

Comment: Yes, only one x-variable. The x-variable is the herbicide dose (g ai per hectare), and the Y-variable is the dry weight of plants per pot (g).

Comment: *Adjusted* R2 adjusts for the number of x variables. If you have only 1 x variable, adjR2 & R2 should be =. Do they differ?

Comment: Yes, they do differ. The adj. R2 values are smaller.

Comment: What are they? What are your data? Are any of c, g, or b variables, or all they all fitted parameters?

Comment: c, g and b are fitted parameters. I have several y-variables, which I am fitting to the regression. For each y-variable, its respective adj. R2 value is smaller than the R2 value.

Answer (score 4):

You are fitting multiple parameters in your model.  (Usually, you fit one parameter for every variable, but your model is non-linear so that isn't the case, even though you have only one $X$ variable.)  With every additional parameter, your model has the opportunity to fit the data better, even if that parameter shouldn't be fitted (e.g., if $b$, or $g$ are actually $1$).  The adjusted $R^2$ statistic attempts to correct for that added flexibility.

$R^2$ doesn't really mean too much on its own.  A low value may be appropriate (that's the amount of information that can legitimately be explained) or it may indicate a problem with lack of fit.  A high value may indicate a particularly informative model, or one that is badly overfit.  What constitutes a "low" or "high" $R^2$ will vary by subject matter.  Etc.  Thus, they are most useful in comparison.  I gather you will fit the same model to multiple $Y$ variables, but if the $X$ variable and the model's functional form are the same each time, it won't make any difference whether you used $R^2$ or $R^2_{\rm adj}$ as long as you used the same one each time.  As far as which should be reported in a paper, $R^2_{\rm adj}$ is probably ideal, but due to its comparative nature, whichever is more common in your field would be appropriate.

Comment: This is not correct. See the answer by https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/169263/30495.

Comment: I've seen the other answer. R2 is just a number, whether it means what people think it means is a different issue, but its completely possible to compute it & it gives the square of the (linear) correlation between the predicted & observed values.

Answer (score 3):

You should use neither of those. This is because neither $R^2$ nor adjusted $R^2$ (for handling multiple explanatory variables) are well defined for non-linear regression. If the purpose is for reporting the accuracy of the models, I would suggest to use cross validation errors, MSE, on a hold out test set instead.

Comment: After doing more research on my own, I see that this is supported in statistics literature, but in my field, most papers report R2. Is there a paper that could be linked to that would support not using R2?

Comment: I do not agree because I would recommend doing all of those test, not one in preference to any other.