# Very high R-squared, should I be suspicious?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, r-squared

I have a dataset of 20 observations which correlate solar panel output with meteorological factors and geographical latitude (a total of 3 predictors). When I build a non-linear regression model for this entire dataset, I get an R-squared of 71%. However, when I divide the dataset into two sets of 10, I get an R-squared of 1.

What puzzles me further is that this is true for both of the two datasets I get by dividing by 2, arbitrarily. When I limit my dataset to the 14 data points which lie north of the equator, I get an R-squared of 73%. Obviously I have too few points south of the equator to compare reasonably right now.

What am I doing wrong? Is the model with R-squared = 1 over explained or something?

To reply to a suggestion, I attach below the residuals-vs-fitted

[image: In response to a request]

In response to Sextus, here is some output from R:

```
lm(formula = yields_differences[11:20] ~ poly(latitudesforplotting[11:20], 
    3) + poly(humidity_average_ordered[11:20], 3) + poly(insolation_annual[21:30], 
    3))
```

Residuals:
ALL 10 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

```
Coefficients:
                                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                                  52.55         NA      NA       NA
poly(latitudes[11:20], 3)1      1632.45         NA      NA       NA
poly(latitudes[11:20], 3)2      2949.47         NA      NA       NA
poly(latitudes[11:20], 3)3      2585.41         NA      NA       NA
poly(humidityvalues[11:20], 3)1 -2450.67         NA      NA       NA
poly(humidityvalues[11:20], 3)2  -854.00         NA      NA       NA
poly(humidityvalues[11:20], 3)3 -4182.23         NA      NA       NA
poly(irradiancevalues, 3)1        -3060.18         NA      NA       NA
poly(irradiancevalues, 3)2         -662.06         NA      NA       NA
poly(irradiancevalues, 3)3        -2318.58         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1,     Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 9 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111227/discussion-on-question-by-abed-very-high-r-squared-should-i-be-suspicious).

Comment: Also:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168599/should-we-report-r-squared-or-adjusted-r-squared-in-non-linear-regression

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen adjusted $R^2$ will not be computable when the non-adjusted $R^2$ is equal to 1, or more specifically when the degrees of freedom for the error are zero. (it will involve a division like 0/0)

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus: I thought about the answer *neither of those*. Anyhow, it seems these is not nonlinear regression at all ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you made some computation error....

When your model fits 10 training data points perfectly but does not predict 10 other testing/validation data points, then you have indeed overfitting.

It is likely that your non-linear model has sufficient flexibility and free parameters to fit any other set of 10 points (even pure noise).

---

You have 20 data points so you should be less worried about overfitting. You could test this with some sort of cross validation. However, maybe you could first consider whether your model really needs 10 parameters to be fitted (I guess your model has so many parameters based on the idea that it perfectly fits any cut of 10 points).

---

In response to your edit: Now it is obviously clear that you are fitting/estimating 10 free parameters/coefficients (and `lm` is not a non-linear model, it is only your predictors which are non linear functions, polynomials, of some input variables). You are estimating 10 parameters (1 intercept and 3x3 coefficients in the 3 polynomials). So that is the reason why you get a perfect fit ($R^2=1$), your problem is over-determined.

Comment: Okay, and would it help then to drop some of the independent variables/parameters? I should point out that I am able to get R-squared above 70% with various other models, so I don't think my approach is crazy.

Comment: @Abed I would't suggest to *drop* a variable, but instead less *free* variables (they can still be in the model, but as fixed). To me a model with such flexibility sounds suspicious, and before considering all kinds of statistical tricks to restrain it, I would consider whether we actually *need* all that flexibility, and maybe  fix or combine some parameters (what's the research question?). I doubt that this exercise (with only 20 points) can be about estimating 10 parameters in a non-linear function of only two variables (and I wouldn't be surprised if that function can be simplified)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sextus. Just to be clear: I do not have 10 parameters, I have three: solar insolation, latitude and humidity. I use these to predict the electric generated by solar PV panels (in fact, it's a bit more complicated than that, but let's go with this for now). My R-squared improves dramatically when I add any one of these three parameters to the model, so for example irradiance alone does not work to determine PV output. Not to start a pattern, but: I would be very happy to chat about this by email for example.

Comment: @abed With parameters I mean the unknown coefficients in the model that you are fitting. Not the variables that are the input of the model.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying that this is not the same thing as the independent variable. This was not entirely clear to me. Anyway, I have 3 independent variables, 1 dependent variables and a training set composed of up to 20 data points. I need to figure out the best model, and some models are suspiciously good, which is what brought me here today.

Comment: @Abed can you explain those models more clearly. Before you had 2 independent variables and now there are 3. You speak about a non-linear model, but how do you make the fit? If you use some software does it give any output that can be used for diagnostics? Without any of this I can only imagine that you are simply having an overdetermined problem (too many free parameters that are used in fitting) which is causing the perfect fit.

Comment: (+1) I don't know why somebody downvoted this. Seems spot on to me.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus okay, I will edit the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Rsquared= 1 indicates that your hypothesis is able to explain the process perfectly which cannot happen and it's a clear sign of overfitting. The reason maybe because your hypothesis is able to capture the trend perfectly by chance since you have very few observations. In short, If you are modelling a random/stochastic process like in your case, you cannot never achieve 100% results.

Comment: I agree with you. It's clearly a case of overfitting and because of high model complexity to model just 10 observations. However, by chance I meant it maybe capturing the random noise which indeed contributes to the overfitting. Thanks for pointing out though.